# curl_exec pulling wrong HTML vs string passed to curl_init

Tags: php, php-curl

My curl request string is created programmatically with a base URL from a database and an integer which is the page number. The string for the URL is correct. If I call the curl request with the base URL copied in to the function, it works. If I call it with the programmatically created string (which is identical) the wrong page is called - it appears to be missing one of the parameters from the string (affiliation):

This has been running for years with no issue. The server is PHP 5.6. The string in the database is stored as varchar(500). I have tried TEXT as the type in the database. I have tried various ways of forcing a string in the function. The first $testurl below is copied and pasted from the second $testurl if I get the code to echo it before making the curl call.

```
//choose one of the $testurls to try
$testurl = 'https://log.concept2.com/challenges/holiday/2019/honorboard/200?country=0&state=&affiliation=1397&sort=distance&page=2';
//In this... $url comes from the database, $gotopage comes from a loop
$testurl = (string)($url . $gotopage);
$c = curl_init($testurl)
$str = curl_exec($c);
curl_close($c);
echo $str; 
die;
```

The first $testurl returns what I want, a list of people in the same team.
The second $testurl returns a list of people belonging to any affiliation.

### Edit

var_dump($testurl) gives:

```
string(134) "https://log.concept2.com/challenges/holiday/2019/honorboard/200?country=0&state=&affiliation=1397&sort=distance&page=2"
```

The full code is more of a challenge. The $GoToPage is an integer. $url is pulled from a database. The pertinent line is:

```
$url = $challenge['mb2_Challenges']['challenge_url'];
```

Where the $challenge is created from a mysqli SELECT... FROM... WHEN... query with SQL. mb2_Challenges is the table, challenge_url is the table.

Comment: What does `var_dump($testurl);` right before the `curl_init()` give you?

Comment: send complete code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those who are as foolish as me, here is the answer:

The string from the script was urlencoded, so `&amp;` instead of `&`. I was in too much of a rush to spot this.  It just needed `htmlspecialchars_decode`.

Lesson learned: always look at the source!